# How to convert type of recogniser's view?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

```
-(void)tapDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{
(UIImageView)(recognizer.view).tag)
    ;}
```

I want to convert type of recognizer's view to imageview so that i  can use tag of image as a reference. how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tag` property is declared in `UIView`, not `UIImageView`. No cast is needed.

```
NSInteger myTag = recognizer.view.tag;
```

For illustration purposes, this is how you would cast the view to `UIImageView` if you wanted, for example, access to its `image` property:

```
UIImage *img = ((UIImageView *)recognizer.view).image;
```

For ease of use, you can use a local variable to make subsequent accesses cleaner:

```
UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)recognizer.view;
UIImage *img = imageView.image;
```

Comment: i have define tag of image view. now i rquired that when i tap on image then print tag of that image on console.

Comment: @ram what are you struggling with?

Comment: i have array of images in image view with scroll view. I want to upload same bigger image  from web service when tap on image .

Comment: @ram this is a much broader topic than your question. I would suggest you ask a new question if you encounter new difficulties.